# Where the TCP open connections are stored in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, linux-kernel

Where the TCP open connections (sockets that didn't received the final ACK yet) are stored in linux kernel ? is there any function that return the open sockets based on the listening port only ?

PS: Kernel 4.15

Comment: `ss` reads the information from `/proc`: https://github.com/sivasankariit/iproute2/blob/master/misc/ss.c#L115

Comment: i mean where are stored in the kernel, in which data structure ? /proc it's a technique used to communicate between kernel space and user space

Comment: In file net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c, look into tcp_hashinfo and seq_file operation which is used by  by /proc/net/tcp